# Issue in NGX effects by passing payload to concatMapTo [actions]

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, rxjs-observables

Below is the effect used to trigger some actions when I load the application. When I run the below code it's throwing error.

```
@Injectable()
export class BootStrapEffects {
  bootStrap$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(GetPrefSuccess),
      map((action) => action.payload),
      concatMapTo((payload: any) => [
        GetUser(payload.parsed.userId),
        GetMenu(payload.parsed.language),
      ])
    )
  })

  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}
}
```

The above code is throwing the below error

```
error TypeError: You provided 'function (payload) { return [
                Object(_app_store_actions_account_action__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["GetUser"])(),
                Object(_app_store_actions_product_action__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__["GetMenu"])()

  ]; }' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

From TSLint

```
Argument of type '() => Observable<never>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => never'.
  Type 'Observable<never>' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replace `concatMapTo` with `concatMap`
`concatMapTo` takes observable as the parameter and doesn't care about what upstream returns, meaning you cannot use payload from upstream.